# How does the save system work in Little Nightmares?

Tags: little-nightmares

The game saves automatically and you can trigger autosave by lighting a torch or a candle found in specified areas in the game:

[image]

Unfortunately when I died, I didn't start from this location but an earlier area. The game had still saved as the torch was lit.

Comment: I stopped playing because of this exact area. Forcing you to replay the WHOLE area is ridiculous. The game is supposed to be scary, instead I am more scared of the ridiculous save checkpoint system not working.

Comment: @CodeCamper: Honestly, getting back to the platforming section only takes a minute. Now I also know that lanterns aren't checkpoints, look forward for my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that lamps aren't checkpoints. The saving icon appears when lighting a lamp, but the game most likely saves to keep track of lit torches and candles for the "Light Up Your Life" [achievement](https://steamcommunity.com/stats/424840/achievements).